# How to execute the except block if try prints an empty string

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I want to search a record in a SQL table and if that record is not found, I want to print an error message. I am using a *try/except* block to do that. But, the error message is not shown. What I think is happening is that when SQL fails to find that record, it won't raise an error. It will just print an empty line. So, the *except* block is not being executed as python thinks the *try* block was executed successfully.

Code:

```py
import mysql.connector as sql

mydb = sql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "password", database = "menagerie")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

try:
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pet  where name='Fluff'")
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    for i in data:
        print(i)

except:
    print("Not found")
```

Here, in the table **pet**, there is no record having the name *Fluff*. So, I want to print the "Not Found" message. But, python prints an empty string.

**If there is any way to solve the problem, whether using try/except or any other method, please do let me know. Thanks.**

Comment: Check if `data` is an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when there are no records satisfying the given condition (`name='Fluff'` in your case), mysql returns an empty set and no error is produced.

```
mysql> select * from job;
+-----+-------------+--------+
| Eno | designation | salary |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|   1 | PGT         |  21000 |
|   3 | TGT         |  19000 |
|   4 | PGT         |  23000 |
|   5 | Primary     |  12000 |
+-----+-------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from job where Eno=7;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Instead of using a `try and except` block, you could check whether `data` is an empty list

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pet  where name='Fluff'")
data = mycursor.fetchall()
if bool(data)==False:
      print("Not found")
else:     
      for i in data:
           print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to include the exception you want so, the exception pop-up:

```
try:
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pet  where name='Fluff'")
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    for i in data:
        print(i)

except sql.Error as err:
    print("Error Code: ", err)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But, here, the except block isn't executing. So, the error code won't be printed.

Comment: Can you provide demo from from your data, please? Because i want to check how many items in your tuple output.

Comment: There are 9 records. Click this link to download the sample database. https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/menagerie-db.zip